# Don't save entity if all properties are null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My ContactInfo class contains all nullable properties (and corresponding database fields), aside from the primary key. ContactInfo is a property on another class, OrgInfo, and in the OrgInfo mapping I have ContactInfo set to Cascade.SaveUpdate(). In my application, OrgInfo is often saved with a null ContactInfo. As a result, NHibernate is inserting a ton of rows in my contact_info table with all the fields null except for the primary key.

My question is: how do I stop NHibernate from inserting these rows and only save when there is at least one property in ContactInfo that is not null? I'm hoping there is a way to do this in the mapping and not with conditional logic and a separate save for ContactInfo.

Thanks in advance

Here is my ContactInfo map:

```
public class ContactInfoMap : ClassMap<ContactInfo> {
    public ContactInfoMap() {
        Table("contact_info");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.ContactInfoId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("contact_info_id");
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("first_name");
        Map(x => x.LastName).Column("last_name");
        Map(x => x.NickName).Column("nickname");
        Map(x => x.AddressStreet1).Column("address_street_1");
        // ... more nullable properties
    }
}
```

And my OrgInfo map:

```
public class OrgInfoMap : ClassMap<OrgInfo> {
    public OrgInfoMap() {
        Table("org_info");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.OrgInfoId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("org_info_id");
        References(x => x.ContactInfo).Column("contact_info_id").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Not.LazyLoad();
        Map(x => x.OrgName).Column("org_name");
        // ... etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use reflection to check

Comment: @AlexKrups Thanks. I have some code setup to do that elsewhere in the app, but I was wondering if nhibernate has any built-in features to handle this scenario.

Comment: @wooters I haven't tried your code, but thinking out loud, have you tried to setting `.Nullable()` on the `References()` part? If that object is not set then i think NH will leave it, though unsure about if the cascade ovverides it.

Comment: @kayess I haven't. That makes sense though. I will try it out, thanks.

Comment: @kayess I tried adding .Nullable(), but unfortunately it didn't work. I am down to my last option: removing the cascade, checking all of the ContactInfo properties to see if they are not null, and doing the insert for ContactInfo separately.